# Multiple views in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following problem:

In Rails I have two Objects: Categories and Items
One category has many items and one item belongs to one category.

Okay. There are no problems.
But now, I want to display all existing categories in a sidebar on every page in my project.

I tried to do display them like:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <p><%= link_to category.title, category %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My root controller is categories. On my starting page the code above will work without any problems.

But when I click on a category I get the following exception:

```
*You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each*

Extracted source (around line #2):
2:     <% @categories.each do |category| %>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to set the @categories variable in the controller.
You can either load the @categories in every action you need to display the sidebar or delegate the request to the view without setting an instance variable.

```
# in the controller

def action
  @categories = ...
end

# or in the view

<div class="sidebar">
  <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
    <p><%= link_to category.title, category %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

If the code spans over multiple views/controllers, I would suggest you to extract the statement in a `before_filter` and/or a partial.

Comment: Thanks!
Now I have added

  before_filter :load_sidebar_categories

  def load_sidebar_categories
    @sb_categories = Category.all
  end
 
in my application controller and it works!